# Почему возникает скролл? Как исправить без { overflow: hidden; }?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/yasakova/pen/mdxZXLp

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Не указывайте никогда `height: 100vh;` для body, иначе это может обрезать контент. А скролл появляется т.к. у body есть `margin: 8px;`, обнулите с помощью `*, ::before, ::after { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: @OliverPatterson, почему это должно обрезать контент?

Comment: там не только у `body` внешние отступы ,но еще и `10px` у дочернего контейнера с заданной высотой в 100%, что само собой делает размеры в сумме больше 100%.

Comment: @Grundy, у меня возникала с этим проблема, что контент уходил за верхнюю границу, если установлена фиксированная высота у body.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, нужно рассматривать каждый случай отдельно, причина могла быть совсем не в установленной высоте

Comment: @Grundy, мне тогда помогло указать минимальную высоту `min-height: 100vh;`, и тогда стало все работает ожидаемым образом. Без указания высоты.

Comment: @OliverPatterson ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ к обрезке контента это не относится

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо огромное